# Save data and close Tkinter window at the same time

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I am trying to get data from the user and then I want the gui window to close, and save the data into variables for my code right after they click "Enter". But the window just stays there. How do I get it to save the data, and the gui window to close at the same time?

```
#pop up window
def show_entry_fields():
   global ModelNumber,PowerOutput,SerialNumber

   ModelNumber=e1.get()
   PowerOutput=e2.get()
   SerialNumber=e3.get()

master = Tk()
master.title("Model Information")

master.geometry("500x300")

master.iconbitmap("square.ico")

Label(master, text="Model Information").grid(row=0,column=1)
Label(master, text="Model Number ").grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="Power Output (w)").grid(row=3)
Label(master,text="Serial Number").grid(row=4)


e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)


e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
e3.grid(row=4, column=1)


Button(master, text='Enter', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=6, 
column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)




mainloop()
master.withdraw()
```

Comment: What do you mean save the data? Save the data to where, a file? By close do you mean close the whole application or a specific window? How does the code you posted relate?

Comment: Right now all you need to do seems to be moving `master.withdraw()` into `show_entry_fields`. But I believe your question is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question. It seems like all you need to do is create a function that does both actions.

```
def save_and_quit()
    show_entry_fields()
    master.quit()

...
button = Button(master, text='Enter', command=save_and_quit)
button.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what I ended up doing.
It does what the show_entry_fields function has inside (which is saving the data as global variables), and it gets ride of the GUI window right after I press "enter"

```
   Button(master, text='Enter',  command=lambda: [f() for f in [show_entry_fields, master.quit]]).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Comment: What you're doing is considered bad practice. You should put `master.quit` inside `show_entry_fields` and if you don't want to disrupt that function, you should instead define a new function that calls both other functions.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to not use `lambda` like this. It makes your code really hard to read, understand, debug, and maintain. Create a proper function.  You should avoid `lambda` unless you absolutely must use it. In this case, there's no reason to use `lambda` at all. It adds complexity without adding any value.